# Create java native method for constructor

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am writing a program in Java and I would like to create a native interface for a library written in C++. But I am confused with how to write a native method declaration for a constructor.

Say I have this C++ class and constructor:

```
 template <class _Tp,class _Val>
  class Arbitrator
  {
  public:
    Arbitrator();
  }
```

How would I write a native method declaration?

This is what I'm doing so far:
package hbot.proxy.bwsal.arbitrator;

```
public class Arbitrator<Tp, Val>
{
    public native Arbitrator Arbitrator();
}
```

Is this how I would do this?

Thanks

Comment: WHat does javah say about your class? If it works, you can use it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create native method. For example, `private native void init()`. Call it from constructor in Java. In it's JNI implementation access C++ class as needed.

You will have to use JNI generated method signatures anyway, so you can't map directly Java class to C++ class if that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: right, I understand that the implementing code will have to use the JNI method signatures, I was just wondering if that would be the correct native declaration of the constructor, or would it be better to do as you say and call a native method from the Java constructor?

Comment: You can't have native constructor. So having `init` method is probably your best shot. I think it's a good style, too.

Comment: What do you do when you want to keep `Init` private in C++? or when you can't modify the class at all?

Answer (score 1):

In order to call a Java class constructor from C++ JNI code, you need to use JNI constructs here.  Assuming you have passed a reference to the JVM with *JNIEnv* in your C++ function like this:

**// Function declaration**

`void
Java_com_hunter_mcmillen_Arbitrator (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {`

**// Reference to the Java class that has your method**

`jclass itemClazz = env->FindClass("com/hunter/mcmillen/myjava/myclasses/Arbitrator");`

**// Reference to the method in your java class**

`jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(itemClazz, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object)V");`

`}`

And now you can actually call the constructor function in your C++ code.